# Jquery onSubmit check some data validation on ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onsubmit

I have a html form when a user submit the form submit event fired and i am validating some data according to input. if validation is ok submit the form or alert the validation error and prevent submit form. 
I am validating user issue quantity with stock in hand quantity.
Help me to solve this issue.

```
ajaxCodeTest = function(){
    var submit_form = true;
    console.log("Click Function is working.");
    $('#issue').html('Please wait...').prop({'disabled':true});
    $('#table_form tbody tr').each(function(index, element){
        var material_code = $(element).find('.material_item_code').val().trim();
        var quantity_issued = $(element).find('.quantity_issued').val().trim();
        var quantity_demanded = $(element).find('#quantity_demanded').val().trim();
        if(quantity_issued > quantity_demanded){
            console.log(material_code+" issue quantity is greater than demanded quantity.");
        }
        var data = url = ''

        data = '&item_code='+material_code;

        url = "{{ route('api.item_info_from_code') }}";

        $.ajax({
            data : data,
            type : 'get',
            url  : url,

            success : function(resp) {
                if(resp == 0) {
                    alert('invalid item code');
                    document.getElementById("issue").disabled = true;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("issue").disabled = false;
                    if(resp.stock_in_hand < quantity_issued){
                        alert(material_code+" stock is not available / stock is lower than than issue quantity.");
                        submit_form = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
            error : function(resp) {
                alert('Oops ! Something went wrong.');
                return 0;
            }

        });
    });
    $('#issue').html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Issue Items').prop({'disabled':false});
    return submit_form;
}
$('#material_user_requisition_issue_items_post').submit(ajaxCodeTest);
```

Comment: since `$.ajax` success callback is called back **asynchronously** (the first A in AJAX stands for asynchronous) `submit_form` will be true when you return it at the end - what you'll need to do is quite simple, but nothing like what you're currently doing

Comment: can you please explain. what should I do and where is the exact mistake I made.

Comment: the exact mistake you made is exactly what I said in the first comment ... `return submit_form` will execute **before** any of the `$.ajax({` get a response, therefore `submit_form` is always true - because Asynchronous code is asynchronous

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks man. any idea for best approach to do it.

Comment: well, I have an idea https://pastebin.com/HmJ2QT19 it's not the "best way" but it's the simplest change to your code - but there is a part missing, because without seeing the form it's not exactly clear how to proceed with the form submit AJAX - you would create FormData from the form and execute another `$.ajax` using the form data, and the form action and form method to "manually" submit the form

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry that i am not familiar with $.when.then . I need to learn more.

Comment: why it is in  $('#table_form tbody tr').each function?

Comment: My table contain multiple item with same input name. When i loop over tr  it is easy to access input for a item/all items.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your help today. Its working now. I Change my submit button to only button and calling the function and I use trigger function to submit the form.